# Not compiling all data

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Unsure what I am doing wrong, I am only getting the value for the first while statement.

The value is calculated correctly, so I do not know what I did wrong.

Maybe someone can see something I cannot. I know you do not have the file it is reading from, but there should not be a need for this.

Any help is appreciated. I always seem to have issues with while loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputFileName;
    string name, gender, college;
    double score = 0, totalCC = 0, totalUN = 0, totalFemalesScore = 0, totalMalesScore = 0;
    int ccCount = 0, unCount = 0, fCount = 0, mCount = 0;
    ifstream inputFile;

    cout << "Input file name: ";
    getline(cin, inputFileName);

    inputFile.open(inputFileName);

    if (!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (inputFile.peek() != EOF)
    {
        inputFile >> name >> gender >> college >> score;
        cout << left << setw(17) << name << setw(4) << gender << setw(4) << college << setw(4) << score << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nEnd of file reached\n" << endl;
    inputFile.clear();
    inputFile.seekg(0);

    while (inputFile >> name)
    {
        inputFile >> gender >> college >> score;
        if (gender == "F")
        {
            totalFemalesScore += score;
            fCount++;
        }
    }
    while (inputFile >> name)
    {
        inputFile >> gender >> college >> score;
        if (gender == "M")
        {
            totalMalesScore += score;
            mCount++;
        }
    }
    while (inputFile >> name)
    {
        inputFile >> gender >> college >> score;
        if (college == "CC")
        {
            totalCC += score;
            ccCount++;
        }
    }
    while (inputFile >> name)
    {
        inputFile >> gender >> college >> score;
        if (college == "UN")
        {
            totalUN += score;
            unCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nEnd of file reached\n" << endl;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Average for females = " << totalFemalesScore / fCount << endl;
    cout << "Average for males = " << totalMalesScore / mCount << endl;
    cout << "Average of CC students = " << totalCC / ccCount << endl;
    cout << "Average of UN students = " << totalUN / unCount << endl;

    inputFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to rewind the file after every loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are accessing the values in these lines of code:

```
while (inputFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    inputFile >> name >> gender >> college >> score;
    cout << left << setw(17) << name << setw(4) << gender << setw(4) << college << setw(4) << score << endl;
}
```

Why not do the computation inside that loop:

```
while (inputFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    inputFile >> name >> gender >> college >> score;
    if (gender == "F")
    {
        totalFemalesScore += score;
        fCount++;
    } else {
        totalMalesScore += score;
        mCount++;
    }
    if (college == "CC")
    {
        totalCC += score;
        ccCount++;
    } else if (college == "UN") {
        totalUN += score;
        unCount++;
    }
    cout << left << setw(17) << name << setw(4) << gender << setw(4) << college << setw(4) << score << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ugh That makes much more sense. Thank you